# Moore method projective geometry

Tags: geometry, lecture-notes, inquiry-based-learning

Has anyone written a set of [Moore method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_method) notes for synthetic *projective* geometry?  It seems like it would be well-suited, but I haven't been able to find any such thing on the Internet.

Comment: Can you describe a bit more about what you mean by "Moore method"?

Comment: @DavidButlerUofA See [**MESE 706**](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/706/) and related links for a start.

Comment: I doubt anyone has written Moore method notes for synthetic anything.

Comment: @PVAL - http://www.jiblm.org/ includes three separate sets of notes on synthetic Euclidean and non-Euclidean geometry.

Comment: A minor point to make the question easier to find, but it might help to add a  <geometry> tag (or a <projective-geometry>  tag, but then the latter would need to be written first, although see http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/projective-geometry/info).

Comment: By the way, are you referring to Miller's [Modern Geometry I](http://www.jiblm.org/downloads/dlitem.php?id=76&category=jiblmjournal) and [Modern Geometry II](http://www.jiblm.org/downloads/dlitem.php?id=79&category=jiblmjournal) and Coppin's [Euclidean and Non-Euclidean Geometries](http://www.jiblm.org/downloads/dlitem.php?id=75&category=jiblmjournal), available from the repository of refereed course notes at http://www.jiblm.org/guides/index.php?category=jiblmjournal, when you mention three sets of notes?

Comment: Also, I wonder whether it would be helpful to use the term *axiomatic*, as it might be more familiar to some than *synthetic*. However, I could be missing a subtle distinction.